# How do I get a particular derived object in a List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, filter

Let's say I have a generic list of `Fruit` (`List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>()`). I then add a couple of objects (all derived from `Fruit`) - `Banana`, `Apple`, `Orange` but with different properties on the derived objects (such as `Banana.IsYellow`).

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
Banana banana1 = new Banana();
Banana banana2 = new Banana();
Apple apple1 = new Apple();
Orange orange2 = new Orange();

fruits.Add(banana1);
fruits.Add(banana2);
fruits.Add(apple1);
fruits.Add(orange1);
```

Then I can do this:

```
foreach(Banana banana in fruits)
    Console.Write(banana.IsYellow);
```

But at execution time of course this is not valid because there is no `IsYellow`-property on the Apple and Orange objects.

How do I get only the bananas, apples, oranges etc from the `List<Fruit>`?

Comment: Does anyone know how to do that in C++ ?? I'm stuck in this dilemma too but I'm writing my code in c++ !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
foreach(Banana b in fruits.OfType<Banana>())
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that one. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

You could just do

```
foreach(Fruit fruit in fruits)
{
   Banana b = fruit as Banana;
   if(b != null)
   {
      Console.Write(b.IsYellow);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: 
First you should make sub-list from Fruit list. To make the sub-list use Generic's `FindAll()` and `Predicate` function.

Step 2: 
Later, in the sub-set you can iterate, which contains only 'Banana'

Here is the code

Step1:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
Banana banana1 = new Banana();
Banana banana2 = new Banana();
Apple apple1 = new Apple();
Orange orange1 = new Orange();

fruits.Add(banana1);
fruits.Add(banana2);
fruits.Add(apple1);
fruits.Add(orange1);

//Extract Banana from fruit list
List<Fruit> bananaComb = fruits.FindAll(IsBanana);

//Now iterate without worring about which fruit it is
foreach (Fruit fruit in bananaComb)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((Banana)fruit).IsYellow);
}
```

Step 2: 
Here comes predicate function

```
//A Predicate function to determine whether its a Banana
static protected bool IsBanana(Fruit aFruit)
{
    return aFruit.GetType().Name == "Banana" ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, however I'm using this is a root UnitOfWork/Repository context so the "list of fruit" is going to contain a lot of objects, making a copy of that isn't a good idea in that context.

Comment: Don't worry. The sub-list is not really a copy, instead, it just hold the pointers that point to 'Banana' on main list.

I already check thru my sample code

To know more about List<t>.FindAll() refer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find this method more readable:

```
foreach(Fruit fruit in fruits)
{
   if (fruit is Banana)
   {
      Banana b = fruit as Banana;
      Console.Write(b.IsYellow);
   }
   else if (fruit is Apple)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You will however receive a slight performance hit and a code analysis warning telling you not to cast unneccessairly because you are essentially doing it twice.

Comment: Ahh, the looping if then else anti pattern [close cousin to the looping case statement].  My eyes they bleed.  Not because of your example here, but these things grow into un maintainable cancers.

Comment: The above comments make sense, but is there something better that avoids the null check in Ian's example. That's the part that makes MY eyes bleed.

Comment: We are talking about fruit, and IsYellow is a derived property of an object state (Color or Colour).  If they all have a Color (which they probably should) then check it.  Generally this pattern is being used instead of using inheritance, not all cases of this are wrong but a substantial amount of the time (most?) it sure seems to be.  SEE Refactoring by Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

adding another syntax, though .OfType< Banana >() is probably the best.

```
foreach (Banana b in fruits.Where(x => x is Banana))
```